# What is the difference between "many of whose" and "many whose"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, possessives

I have two examples:

> If you do try to discuss these new beliefs with them, **many of whose** minds are closed to new ideas will fight hard to keep themselves convinced and even try to change your mind back as well

and

> If you do try to discuss these new beliefs with them, **many whose** minds are closed to new ideas will fight hard to keep themselves convinced and even try to change your mind back as well.

What is the difference between "many of whose" and "many whose"? Do they have the same meaning and can they be interchangeable?

Comment: They both are correct, and bear the same meaning. But of course, they are not the same structure.

Answer (score -1):

Your sentences are describing a smaller group of a general population, one way it can be said is

> some *of* a population
>   many *of* a population
>   a few *of* a population
>   all *of* a population

another way this can be said is to just mention the quantity directly

> many *something*
>   some *something*
>   a few *something*
>   all *somethings*

Both of your sentences are correct.

Comment: I don't understand how the first sentence is correct. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: "Some of the population"?

Comment: The first sentence in the original post. "If you do try to discuss these new beliefs with them, many of whose minds are closed to new ideas will fight hard to keep themselves convinced and even try to change your mind back as well." I can't figure out a grammatical parse of it.